# How to apply angular DataTable?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-datatables

I am working on Angular 6 and i want to apply angular data table but its giving below error. How can I resolve below error and apply Angular data table.

getting bellow error.

```
ERROR TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at eval (angular-datatables.umd.js:46)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:264)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:496)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
    at timer (zone.js:2054)
```

I have follow this https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started URL for datatable.

I have installed all the below dependencies in my project.

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install datatables.net --save
npm install datatables.net-dt --save
npm install angular-datatables --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
npm install @types/datatables.net --save-dev
```

I have added below files in my _Layout file in HEAD tag.

```
<link href="~/node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

After that I have added below lines in Systemjs.Config.js file

```
'jquery': 'npm:jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'datatables.net': 'npm:Datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js',
'angular-datatables': 'npm:angular-datatables/bundles/angular-datatables.umd.js',
```

Import datatable in app.module.ts

```
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, DataTablesModule],
    providers: []  //declared employee component also as a root component
})
```

At last below is my html file

```
<h1> This is our TL Dashboard</h1>
<table border="1" datatable class="table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>BASIC</td>
            <td>DEPARTMENT NAME</td>
            <td>DESIGNATION DESC</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of EmployeeDetails.Table1">
            <td>{{employee.EMP_NAME}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: I am using  "@angular/cli": "^6.0.0",

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `$` on the top of your component class like this -

```
declare var $ = any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
.....
```

PS: Also it's good practice to add all dependencies like jQuery etc in `angular.json` file, not in the index.html file

Comment: Thanks @Pradeep for your response. Can you please explain in details so I can understand what changes need to be done in my code.